# XPath: Select from non-root node fails

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to select nodes starting from nodes that are not root nodes of XML documents. The code the following:

```
 foreach (XmlNode xmlIter in root.SelectNodes("/refentry/refsect1[@id='parameters']/variablelist/*")) {
    Parameter p = new Parameter();

    xmlNode = xmlIter.SelectSingleNode("varlistentry/term/parameter");
    p.Identifier = xmlNode.InnerText;

    xmlNode = xmlIter.SelectSingleNode("varlistentry/listitem");
    p.Documentation = xmlNode.InnerText;
}
```

The XML document (here is only a snippet) is the following:

```
<refsect1 id="parameters"><title>Parameters</title>
    <variablelist>
    <varlistentry>
        <term><parameter>pipeline</parameter></term>
        <listitem>
        <para>

        </para>
        </listitem>
    </varlistentry>
    <varlistentry>
        <term><parameter>program</parameter></term>
        <listitem>
        <para>

        </para>
        </listitem>
    </varlistentry>
    </variablelist>
</refsect1>
```

But the above code doesn't work: the *xmlNode* variable is always null... What's wrong?

Comment: Interesting thing today.  Upgraded my app from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.8 and my xpath expression stopped returning nodes.  Using your XML, the following xpath.
"/refsect1" succeeds in .NET 3.5 but returns null in .NET 4.8 ( and so does "refsect1").  I have to change all my xpath to use // so that a xpath search punches through the inability to reference through the root node.  I think it's a .NET 4.8 bug.  Not seeing chatter about it yet.

Comment: It's slightly more processor intensive, my XML files are small so it's OK. Changed to "//varlistentry[term/parameter='pipeline']"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leading "/" means "start at the root of the document". Try just:

```
xmlNode = xmlIter.SelectSingleNode("varlistentry/term/parameter");
p.Identifier = xmlNode.InnerText;

xmlNode = xmlIter.SelectSingleNode("varlistentry/term/listitem");
p.Documentation = xmlNode.InnerText;
```

(If you're using .NET 3.5 or later I'd personally use LINQ to XML instead - I find it easier to use than XPath, but that's a different matter. I can provide the equivalent LINQ to XML code if you want.)

EDIT: Got it. Your `[stuff]/variablelist/*` query is already going into the `varlistentry` node - you're then trying to find another `varlistentry` node *beneath* it. If you select all the `varlistentry` elements instead, you only need to find the `term/parameter` and `listitem` elements under that `varlistentry`.

This works:

```
foreach (XmlNode xmlIter in doc.SelectNodes
         ("/refentry/refsect1[@id='parameters']/variablelist/varlistentry"))
{
    XmlNode xmlNode = xmlIter.SelectSingleNode("term/parameter");
    Console.WriteLine("Identifier = {0}", xmlNode.InnerText);

    xmlNode = xmlIter.SelectSingleNode("listitem");
    Console.WriteLine("Documentation = {0}", xmlNode.InnerText);
}
```

Mind you, it would probably still be worth validating that `xmlNode` is non-null before using it.

Comment: I'm fixed on .NET 2. BTW, I've already tried this and it doesn't work... I did a double check! (I've also fixed the second path: it was wrong, but it returns null all the same).

Comment: @Luca: I've found the problem and edited my answer with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

`//refentry/refsect1[@id='parameters']/variablelist` gives you all `variablelist` nodes respecting the preceding 2 nodes whatever their position in your xml file is. This is however not nice for you perforamce, so if you need any performance you should always start navigating at your rootnode which is `/`

Comment: It requires the trailing * (otherwise it throw an exception). However, this doesn't work. I've tried also with *xmlIter.SelectSingleNode("/varlistentry/listitem")*, but no luck.

Comment: maybe try //refentry/refsect1[@id='parameters']/variablelist

Comment: It has worked, but the *root.SelectNodes* routine returns only the first child, but there are more.